# How to add users (authors) to favourites in WordPress?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, metadata

I have a function that lists out users in a members directory. I want to give the option to save a user and display it on a list of saved users (members), in WordPress authors.

I have the following code, but keep on having an error when saving, it gives a post 400. The response is 0.

The user that is being saved, needs to be stored in the metadata of the one saving it.

PHP

```
   function display_users($args = array(), $show_all_users = true) {
        $defaults = array(
            'orderby' => 'ID',
            'order' => 'ASC',
            'role' => 'subscriber', // Add this line to filter by role
            'search' => ''
        );
        $args = wp_parse_args($args, $defaults);
    
        $wp_user_query = new WP_User_Query($args);
    
        if (!empty($wp_user_query->results)) {
            $output = '<div class="user-grid">';
            foreach ($wp_user_query->results as $user) {
                // Check if only favorites should be displayed
                if (!$show_all_users) {
                    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
                    echo $user_id;
                    $favorites = get_user_meta($user_id, 'favorites', true);
                    print_r($favorites);
                    if (!in_array($user->ID, $favorites)) {
                        // If user is not in favorites list, skip to the next user
                        continue;
                    }
                }
    
                $output .= '<div class="user">';
                $output .= '<a href="' . get_author_posts_url($user->ID) . '">';
                $output .= '<div class="user-image">' . get_avatar($user->ID, 150) . '</div>';
                if (get_field('mepr_open_to_connect', 'user_' . $user->ID) == 'always-feel-free-to-reach-out') {
                    $output .= '<p class="user-connect">Let\'s connect</p>';
                }
                $output .= '<div class="user-name">' . get_field('first_name', 'user_' . $user->ID) . '</div>';
                $output .= '<div class="user-info">';
                $output .= '<p class="user-current-work">' . get_field('mepr_current_work', 'user_' . $user->ID) . '</p>';
                $output .= '</div>';
                // Add favorite button
                if (is_user_logged_in()) {
                    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
                    $favorites = get_user_meta($user_id, 'favorites', true);
                    $is_favorite = in_array($user->ID, $favorites);
                    $output .= '<button class="favorite-button" data-user-id="' . $user->ID . '" data-is-favorite="' . $is_favorite . '">' . ($is_favorite ? 'Remove from favorites' : 'Add to favorites') . '</button>';
                }
                $output .= '</a>';
                $output .= '</div>';
            }
            $output .= '</div>';
    
            return $output;
        }
    }
    
    // add to favourites function
    function save_user_favorites() {
        // Verify nonce
        if ( ! isset( $_POST['nonce'] ) || ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['nonce'], 'save_user_favorites' ) ) {
            wp_send_json_error( 'Invalid nonce' );
        }
    
        // Check if user is logged in
        if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
            wp_send_json_error( 'User not logged in' );
        }
    
        // Get user ID
        $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    
        // Get favorites
        $favorites = isset( $_POST['favorites'] ) ? $_POST['favorites'] : array();
    
        // Update user meta
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'favorites', $favorites );
    
        wp_send_json_success();
    }

add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_save_user_favorites', 'save_user_favorites' );
 add_action( 'wp_ajax_save_user_favorites', 'save_user_favorites' );
```

jquery

```
    <script defer>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  // Add event listener to favorite buttons
  $('.favorite-button').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var button = $(this);
    var userId = button.data('userId');
    var isFavorite = button.data('isFavorite');
    var favorites = button.data('favorites');

    // Add or remove user from favorites
    if (isFavorite) {
      var index = favorites.indexOf(userId);
      if (index !== -1) {
        favorites.splice(index, 1);
      }
    } else {
      var favorites = button.data('favorites') || [];
    }

    // Save favorites to meta data
    button.data('favorites', favorites);
    button.data('isFavorite', !isFavorite);
    $.post(ajaxurl, {
  'action': 'save_user_favorites',
  'favorites': favorites,
  'nonce': '<?php echo wp_create_nonce( "save_user_favorites" ); ?>'
});


    // Toggle button text and data attribute
    button.text(isFavorite ? 'Add to favorites' : 'Remove from favorites');
  });
  
  // Load favorites from localStorage
var favorites = localStorage.getItem('favorites');
if (favorites !== null) {
    favorites = JSON.parse(favorites);
} else {
    favorites = [];
}


  // Load favorites from meta data
  $('.favorite-button').each(function() {
    var button = $(this);
    var userId = button.data('userId');
    var favorites = button.data('favorites');
    var isFavorite = favorites && favorites.includes(userId);
    button.text(isFavorite ? 'Remove from favorites' : 'Add to favorites');
    button.data('isFavorite', isFavorite);
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: where is jquery script?

Comment: @Vel, my bad, I've uploaded it. Thanks!

Comment: where ajax call action hook?

Answer (score 0):

This hooks are missing in you functions.php

```
 add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_save_user_favorites', 'save_user_favorites' );
 add_action( 'wp_ajax_save_user_favorites', 'save_user_favorites' );
```

Comment: Thank you, lost this part along the way. Got some problems copying my code, my bad.
No everything seems to work, without any error, but it's not saved. So on page reload, the ones I've "saved" are back to not saved.